# Is there a way to recognize if I'm running app from XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

For example, I would like to connect to my Local DataBase if I am running from XCode (simulator or connected iPhone).

And if its not running from XCode I would connect to my Web DataBase.

I've seen something like:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
```

but I'm not sure if it would work for simulating on device.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  This means that you will have a code that can only run without an attached debugger.  So if you have a crash there, have fun debugging it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine if your app is being run under the debugger with the following code from [Technical Q&A QA1361](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1361/_index.html).

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

static bool AmIBeingDebugged(void)
    // Returns true if the current process is being debugged (either 
    // running under the debugger or has a debugger attached post facto).
{
    int                 junk;
    int                 mib[4];
    struct kinfo_proc   info;
    size_t              size;

    // Initialize the flags so that, if sysctl fails for some bizarre 
    // reason, we get a predictable result.

    info.kp_proc.p_flag = 0;

    // Initialize mib, which tells sysctl the info we want, in this case
    // we're looking for information about a specific process ID.

    mib[0] = CTL_KERN;
    mib[1] = KERN_PROC;
    mib[2] = KERN_PROC_PID;
    mib[3] = getpid();

    // Call sysctl.

    size = sizeof(info);
    junk = sysctl(mib, sizeof(mib) / sizeof(*mib), &info, &size, NULL, 0);
    assert(junk == 0);

    // We're being debugged if the P_TRACED flag is set.

    return ( (info.kp_proc.p_flag & P_TRACED) != 0 );
}
```

Tested successfully under simulator and device (iPhone 4, iOS 5.0.1).

> **Important** Because the definition of the kinfo_proc structure (in
>   ) is conditionalized by __APPLE_API_UNSTABLE, you should
>   restrict use of the above code to the debug build of your program.

Comment: How should I use this function properly? Thow in my code and use like: bool debugMode = AmIBeingDebugged(); ?

Comment: Sure, that would work. But placing it in a seperate file which gets imported in those classes actually needing it seems more appropriate.

Comment: I am getting this error: Semantic Issue: Static declaration of 'AmIBeingDebugged' follows non-static declaration

Comment: Strange. I can place that function wherever I want without getting any errors... Maybe you should place that function outside of your `@implementation` or `@interface`. Take a look at how it's done here and see if that helps: https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCIntrospect/blob/master/DCIntrospect/DCIntrospect.m

Answer (score 1):

You could have the compiler select different code in your builds, depending on different pre-processor macros in your Debug versus Release Build settings.  Debug could use local, and Release use the web.